# count with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have two table:

```
Name
    id | name | city_id
    1  | aaa  | 1
    2  | vvv  | 2
    3  | ddd  | 2
    4  | sss  | 3
    5  | dds  | 1
```

etc

```
City:
id | name
1  | London
2  | NY
3  | Boston
```

etc

how can i get City and count:

```
name_city | count
London    | 2
NY        | 2
Boston    | 1
```

In City table:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('a')
           ->leftJoin('a.Name n')
           ->select('a.name_city as name_city, sum(n.city_id) as sum');

        return $q->execute();
```

but this is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `count()` instead of `sum()`, and plus, you need a `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not appear to have a `FROM` clause, the object type is not specified for the `a` entity.

Also, read the [aggregate values section in the documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en#select-queries%3aaggregate-values).

Answer (score 1):

this post was kinda helpful but I though that I would add a little more details for anyone looking to join 2 tables and with an aggregate count.

e.g. this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837671/mysql-join-tables-and-count-instances) but in doctrine.

Using the example above the query would be (doctrine 2.0):

```
$q = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('a')
           ->select('a.name_city as name_city, count(n.city_id) as sum');
           ->from('city','a')
           ->leftJoin('a.Name n')
           ->groupBy('n.id')
           ->orderBy('sum')

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    echo $qb->getDql();  // if you want to see the dql created
    $result = $query->getResult();
```