# MySQL Join tables and count instances

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have the following tables:

```
Countries
---------------------------
| ID | Country Name       |
---------------------------
| 1  | Greece             |
| 2  | Italy              |
| 3  | Spain              |
---------------------------

Cities
---------------------------
| ID | City               |
---------------------------
| 1  | Athens             |
| 2  | Patra              |
| 3  | Rome               |
| 4  | Venice             |
---------------------------

Countries & Cities
--------------------
| ID | Cntr | City |
--------------------
| 1  |   1  |   2  |
| 2  |   1  |   1  |
| 3  |   2  |   3  |
--------------------
```

Now, How can I run a MySQL query that will return the name of the countries and the total cities based on table "Countries & Cities" ?

In example to return:

```
---------------------------
| Cities | Country        |
---------------------------
| 2      | Greece         |
| 1      | Italy          |
---------------------------
```

Comment: Strange design. Unless you really have a need to have a city belong to more than one country, I'd think you could eliminate the "Countries & Cities" table and add a simple CountryID (FK) column in the Cities table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT COUNT(cs.City) as Cities, cn.name as Country
FROM countries cn 
INNER JOIN country_city cs ON cs.Cntr = cn.id 
GROUP BY cn.name
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2   | Greece
1   | Italy
```

Comment: is it really neccesary to join with the city table? the only additional information there is the cityname which is not used.

Comment: @Flo : very good point, checked it and returned the same. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cn.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM CountriesAndCities cc
JOIN Countries cn ON (cn.ID = cc.Cntr)
GROUP BY cn.Name
```

Comment: This will not work because cn.Name is not contained in any aggregate function

Comment: try to run it, for me it gives `Column '@countries.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Now after your edit it should work fine since cn.Name is in GROUP BY columns list ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one JOIN is needed

```
SELECT `c`.`name`, COUNT(`c`.id) 
FROM `countries_cities` AS `cc`
JOIN `countries` AS `c`
ON `c`.id = `cc`.country_id
GROUP BY `cc`.country_id
```

Comment: This will not work because c.Name is not contained in any aggregate function

Comment: Strange, can you take a look at this article  http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/u.cgi/err979/mysql I tried to run your query on Sql Server and it gives me error

Comment: @sll, author of the question uses MySQL, there is no specific constructions, IMHO it's SQL92

Comment: You mean that page http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/u.cgi/err979/mysql provides a wrong information regarding GROUP BY constraints? Especially `c.name` is not fit those requirements

Comment: please do not continue this discussion, read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You only need to group the countries in the countries & cities table:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), c.Name 
FROM [countriesAndCities] cnc 
INNER JOIN [country] c ON cnc.cnt = c.id
GROUP BY c.Name
```